# after_filter or Sidekiq for managing a page_view information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

I have a Rails app and currently I create a PageView object for each API access. Our API is still pretty fast (50% of request are < 50ms) but most of the time is spent in writing the PageView to our MySQL instance.

I was thinking of using Sidekiq but the problem has been passing larger objects which are strongly discouraged in Sidekiq - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-jobs-input-small-and-simple

What would be a better option? Our current solution of an after_filter is OK but would just like to get more performance.

### Edit

I am trying to not have scenarios like this (granted an isolated incident of 1 request but using a cloud MySQL provider):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

mysql is really quite fast.  Your time is probably spent in AR validations or callbacks.  Drop down to a raw DB connection and SQL to cut as much Ruby out:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
  conn.insert "INSERT INTO ..."
end
```

Comment: agreed that a mysql insert is pretty fast - but the only op we are doing is a redis get; would be great to go from ~55ms -> 20ms; love sidekiq btw.